# Retrieveing data from Firebase database in Swift 3, issue

Tags: iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am using the Firebase on swift 3 for last 2 month.
At the middle of our application development, some iPhone Devices shows issues on fetching the data from Firebase realtime database.

my code is

```
var databaseReference: FIRDatabaseReference!
databaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
databaseReference = databaseReference.child("_general")
databaseReference.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:
    { (snapshot) in
        // Get value
        print("Snapshot ",snapshot)
}) { (error) in
    print("ERROR ",error)
}
```

In some devices the following log is showing:

```
2016-12-02 15:29:02.507003 DatabaseExampleSwift[273:15534] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 7 Connection has no connected handler
```

[image]

Comment: The "observeSingleEvent " handler is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this help

```
let baseUrl = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let generalRef = baseUrl.child("_general")

    generalRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        print("This is snapshot value: \(snapshot)")
    }) { (error) in
        print("Failed to get snapshot", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you accidentally deleted the node or you have changed the Google info list